# Changing the value of one input when another is filled?

Tags: javascript, onchange

Im trying to create a javascript function that sets the value of one input, when another one is changed. Heres my javascript (that isnt working):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addvalue(formname)

{
document.formname.elements.description.value = "filgerng";

}
</script>
```

And here are my two elements:

```
<input id="firstfile"  type="file" class="fileupload" name="files[]" size=
"80" onchange="addvalue(this.form)" />
<input id="firstdescription" type="text" name="description" size="50"
 />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your function at:

```
document.formname.elements.description.value = "filgerng";
```

Actually, `elements` is an array, use :

```
document.formname.elements[indexofthecontrol].description.value = "filgerng";
```

Plus, try to avoid `this.form`. This is not well handled by every browsers.

You'd better use a

```
document.getElementById('firstdescription').value="thisorthat";
```

Comment: Perfect! .. One little part im trying to add that i cant seem to get working.. i only want it to add a value if the user hasnt put in their own yet... 
`<script type="text/javascript">
function addvalue()

{
if (document.getElementById('firstdescription').value == "";) {

document.getElementById('firstdescription').value="thisorthat";

}
}
</script>`

Comment: Nevermind! Figured it out on my own :)   (.value.length == 0)

Comment: Or `value==""` or even better, `(value.lenght===0 || value!=element.defaultValue)` this way you can have a placeholder such as "yourtexthere".